# Copy ESXi vm image to vSphere

Tags: vmware

It is possible to copy image from a VMware ESXi 5.0 server to a vSphere 5.0 server.

Is there any compatibility issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

not a problem. i would use esxi File->Export->Export OVF Template. then you can deploy the exported ovf template into vsphere5 vcenter. I am assuming by vSphere 5.0 server you mean vcenter, as opposed to standalone hypervisor esxi5.0.

you could also just copy files with file system commands (with the vm shut down) from one place to another, but ovf is more robust and general more optimized.

if your vcenter still have extra license, you can also add the esxi5.0 host to the vcenter temporarily (if the host is reachable from the vcenter) and you can then just clone the vm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose host you want to up image. After you choose configuration/storage. Click right storage --> Browse Datastore, you can export/import image.